# PHQL UNION Query in Phalcon Framwork

Tags: union, phalcon

In yesterday, I got an issue when I made a query statement with UNION in Phalcon and I got an error. I found about this issue in internet. But seem UNION wasn't supported. Anybody know about this?

```
$phql = "SELECT DISTINCT key, type FROM (
          (SELECT DISTINCT key, type FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB    WHERE b.id =  $userId)
          UNION
          (SELECT DISTINCT key, type FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableC WHERE c.id IN $groupIds)
) ";
```

Comment: Show php code and error message

Comment: This is an error showing : 
    when parsing: SELECT DISTINCT key, type FROM ( (SELECT DISTINCT key, type FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB WHERE TableB.id = 1) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT key, type FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableC WHERE TableB.id IN (1)) ) (401)" ["file"]=> string(77) "/Test.php" ["line"]=> int(161) ["trace"]=> string(1459) "#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->parse() #1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->execute(NULL, NULL)

Comment: ##This my codes ##


`$phql = "SELECT DISTINCT key, type FROM (  
             (SELECT DISTINCT key, type FROM TableA INNER JOIN    TableB WHERE TableB.id =  $this->id)
              UNION
            (SELECT DISTINCT key, type FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableC WHERE TableC.id IN $groupIds)
                    )
                    ";
            
   $resources = \Helper::$di->get('modelsManager')->executeQuery($phql);`

Comment: `INNER JOIN` without `ON` looks odd in your case. Do you try to make `cross join` query or just forgot to add `ON` clause? And what about `b` and `c`? You didn't set aliases.

Comment: When you use Phalcon, if you have defined in model . Example with table TableA you will have TableA.php. In this, you will define:

$this->hasMany("id", "TableB", "b_id"); //something like that.

and Phalcon will auto generate, you dont need use ON conditions for INNER JOIN statement 
Please refer:
[http://docs.phalconphp.com/fr/latest/reference/phql.html]

Answer (score 2):

What you can check:
 1. Check that your **$groupIds** is not array. It should be a string only in format "(1,2,3)" to use it after **IN**
 2. Give names for all your tables in query (like in my example *p1, p2, p3*)
 3. It is safer to pass params into your query, not the real variables

**Example** (*Following code works well*):

```
$db = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('db');
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT p3.id, p3.name FROM (
        (SELECT DISTINCT p1.id, p1.name FROM project p1 where p1.id = :from)
        UNION
        (SELECT DISTINCT p2.id, p2.name FROM project p2 where p2.id IN (:to))
    ) p3
");
$stmt->execute(['from' => 3, 'to' => implode(',', array(8))]);
$created = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: This will not work properly if you use more than one 'to' values. Implode will give you concatenated string (e.g. `"8,9,10"`) that will also be parsed as a string at DB level. DB will execute query: `SELECT DISTINCT p2.id, p2.name FROM project p2 where p2.id IN ("8,9,10")` which is probably not what you were expecting.